# Converting string to key_t

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory, sysv-ipc

How is it possible to convert a string to a `key_t`, in order to use it for creating a shared memory segment by using `shmget`?

This is because the key for mapping the shared memory is being transmitted over TCP/IP.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I *think* you're looking for [`ftok()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/ftok.html). The string can't be arbitrary. It has to be an actual `stat()`-able file system entity.

Comment: If not, how are you arriving at the string in the first place?

Comment: After using ftok() to obtain the required key, I am sending this key over TCP/IP in the form of a string. Once the sting is received at the client side I want to convert the received string back to the generated key from the server side. Is this possible? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is created by a call to `ftok()`. The latter uses a file path and an 8bit value to do so.

For the same file path and the same 8bit value `ftok()` (re-)creates the same key.

So transfer the file path and the 8bit value (typically another `char`) and let the receiver call `ftok()` on the values received. This will create the same key as the sender uses.

From [`ftok()`'s documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ftok.3.html):

> The  **ftok()**  function uses the identity of the file named by the given pathname (which must refer to an existing, accessible file) and the least significant 8 bits of proj_id (which must be nonzero)
>          to generate a key_t type System V IPC key, suitable for use with **msgget(2)**, **semget(2)**, or **shmget(2)**.
>
> The resulting value is the same for all pathnames that name the same file, when the same value of proj_id is used.  The value returned should be different when the (simultaneously existing) files or
>          the project IDs differ.

Comment: Can you please specify exactly why the project id is useful in relation with the ftok() please?

Comment: @Bran: Because the man-pages says so. It's "*useful*" in the sense that it is necessary.

Comment: OK. As the shared memory is dependent on the key, why is not possible to generate the key from the server side and send it to the client side, rather than transfering the file path and the 8-bit value?

Comment: @Bran: Transferring binary data from one process to another is error prone, as the interpretation of the (binary) data can be different on both sides, however it **could** work, but "*could*" shall not be enough. Transfering character data (as the 8bit value also can be looked at) is fail-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the receiver interprets the data in the same way that the sender put them on the line.

E.g., if the sender does

```
char buf[32];
*((key_t*)buf) = data;
```

and sends the 32 byte buffer over the net, the receiver should read them into a matching buffer and extract the `key_t` using

```
data = *((key_t*)buf);
```

Comment: How exactly this can be done please? Apart sending each corresponding byte what exactly do I need to do? Thanks!

Comment: My original answer referred to Marshalling, which (on second thought) isn't much help for a binary value. Updated the answer to a simple way of sending end receiving such values.